# iOS9 App Transport Security: Allow insecure HTTP loads only on certain subpages

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios9, app-transport-security

Is there a way to allow insecure HTTP loads only on certain subpages of a domain without allowing insecure HTTP loads for the entire domain?

In my app I'm getting data from an API that I reach under the domain

`https://example.com/api/...`

The whole API uses HTTPS so I want to disallow insecure HTTP loads there.

In another part of the app I need to display a privacy and a terms & conditions HTML page in a UIWebView. The URLs for this pages are

`http://example.com/privacy`

and

`http://example.com/terms`

These two pages are only available as HTTP, so I have to allow insecure HTTP loads for them. But I want to allow insecure loads for **only** these 2 URLs, while enforcing HTTPS for the rest of the domain.

Does anybody know if that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The most granularity you have is with subdomains, so you could for example enforce secure connections for `api.example.com` but allow insecure loads for `example.com`, excluding subdomains.

Comment: I already suspected that it was not possible. Thanks for the clarification!